# Explicit tensor product decomposition for the representations of PSL(2,q)

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, unitary-representations

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$Let the *type* of the character theory of a finite group $G$ be the list $[[d_1,n_1], \dotsc,  [d_k,n_k]]$ with $1=d_1 < \dotsb < d_k$ and $n_i$ the number of irreducible characters of degree $d_i$.

There is a global understanding of the character theory of the finite groups $\PSL(2,q)$ with $q$ a prime power,

- if $q \equiv 0 \pmod2$, it is of type $[[1,1],[q-1,\frac{q}{2}],[q,1],[q+1,\frac{q-2}{2}]]$,
- if  $q \equiv 1 \pmod4$, it is of type $[[1,1],[\frac{q+1}{2},2],[q-1,\frac{q-1}{4}],[q,1],[q+1,\frac{q-5}{4}]]$,
- if  $q \equiv 3 \pmod4$, it is of type $[[1,1],[\frac{q-1}{2},2],[q-1,\frac{q-3}{4}],[q,1],[q+1,\frac{q-3}{4}]]$,

and according to these three cases, there is a global way to write the character table of $\PSL(2,q)$. It was first computed by H. Jordan ([Group-Characters of Various Types of Linear Groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1506021), 1907). The table is directly available in [Character table of $\PSL(2, \mathbb F_q)$](http://www2.math.umd.edu/%7Ejda/characters/psl2/) of J. Adams (see also his detailed note [Character tables for $\operatorname{GL}(2)$, $\operatorname{SL}(2)$, $\operatorname{PGL}(2)$, and $\PSL(2)$ over a finite field](http://www2.math.umd.edu/%7Ejda/characters/characters.pdf) for the proof).

The character table of a finite group $G$ and the [Schur orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations) provide the Grothendieck ring (where $n_{i,j}^k \in \mathbb{N}$): $$ \chi_i \chi_j = \sum_k n_{i,j}^k \chi_k. $$
Let $U_i$ be an irreducible unitary representation related to the character $\chi_i$. Then there are $G$-isomorphisms $\Phi_{i,j}$:
$$ \Phi_{i,j} : U_i \otimes U_j \to \bigoplus_k M_{i,j}^k \otimes U_k $$ with $M_{i,j}^k$ a multiplicity space of dimension $n_{i,j}^k$.

> **Question**: What are explicit maps $\Phi_{i,j}$ for $G = \PSL(2,q)$, with a global understanding (as for the character
> table)?

Comment: There are two typos in the second table that Jeffrey Adams put [here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jda/characters/psl2/)  (I just pointed out to him): first line: (q-7)/4 should be (q-3)/4; last column, middle line: 1 should be -1.